# Storing filtered file based on condition for later use?

Tags: python, arcpy

I want to filter the file `roads` that exists in the Default.gdb so its field 'SZ' will only have rows that start with 'UWN' and store that filtered file to a variable.

Code:(it works well I just don't know how to store the filtered file)

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Users\user\Documents\ArcGIS\Default.gdb'

datasetList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*')

          
for dataset in datasetList:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["SZ"]) as cur:
        for row in cur:
           if row[0].startswith('UWN') #filter whole field to only have rows that start with 'UWN'.
         ???   how can I store this filtered file so I continue with this? <---------
```

What are the proper ways to do this?

Replacement or just store it in a variable?

How to store the other columns too, based on this filtering?

## **update**:

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\a\Roads'):
   for i in files:
       if i.endswith('shp'):
           arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(i,i  ,"SZ" LIKE "UWN%")
```

> Parsing error SyntaxError: invalid syntax (line 5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cursor is not returning a file, it is returning each row in the feature class. You have only specified SZ field, so this is the only value that is returned. So you will not get anything to export except this field. It would be possible to insert the rows into a new feature class using the insertcursor, but there are much easier ways of copying selected rows.

So you should not use cursors for this. Instead use [Select](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/select.htm):

> Extracts features from an input feature class or input feature layer,
>   typically using a select or Structured Query Language (SQL) expression
>   and stores them in an output feature class.

With a SQL expression. This will output a new feature class with only the selected rows.

If you dont want to export all fields it would be better to use MakeFeatureLayer with a SQL statement and then Copy Features, for example:

```
sql = """{0} LIKE 'UWN%'""".format(arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(datasource=dataset, field='SZ'))
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(in_features=dataset, out_layer='templyr', 
                                 where_clause=sql)
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(in_features='templyr', out_feature_class='someoutputname')
```

Comment: yes I would rather not involve a geodatabase. Can you suggest an implementation using code of what  I have written but with your idea to better comprehend it? Thanks

Comment: I see that makefeature layer management allows a where clause. Can I mention there the condition for field 'SZ' to start with 'UWN'? Can you elaborate on this?Maybe I can do this without the select_analysis?

Comment: It gives error check the update to see what I wrote.

Comment: Isn't there a more straightforward way that doesn't use AddFieldDelimiters? similar to `"SZ" LIKE "UWN%"`

Comment: Yes, but the code will break if you input something other than a shapefile since different inputs use different field delimiters: "" '' [] etc.